# Can't drop or alter a PROCEDURE from within another stored routine - EF Core Migrations

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm trying to run a SP in MySQL to apply an EF Core Migration conditionally.
In my script I do the following:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MigrationsScript;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE MigrationsScript()
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `__EFMigrationsHistory` WHERE `MigrationId` = 
'MigrationName') THEN

    -- Insert commands

    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
CALL MigrationsScript();
DROP PROCEDURE MigrationsScript;
```

However I'm receiving the following error: "MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Can't drop or alter a PROCEDURE from within another stored routine"
The reason I'm using a SP for this, is that MySQL doesn't support "IF" statements as SQL Server does, so in order to apply this migration conditionally I had to do it this way.
The error message seems misleading to me, as I'm not calling DROP PROCEDURE command from within any other routine or SP.
I'm using POMELO driver for MySQL, EF Core 6.0.4 and the project is running Net Core 6.
I've read the other similar posts about this error but none of them describes this particular scneario, I'm not using quotes in delimiters neither trying to drop a SP from within another SP.

Comment: *MySQL doesn't support "IF" statements as SQL Server does* Use INSERT commands in the next form: `INSERT INTO tablename ({columns set}) SELECT {values set} WHERE EXISTS ({your condition})`. [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c3fe490eb78b64c259844e3d7b2180b6)

Comment: Thank you Akina, I may try your suggestion as the last attempt, because I actually have 800 insert statements to do inside the SP, so adding that condition to each line won't be easy, but that's a step forward on the right direction, no doubts. If I can't find another solution I'll apply it and close this question.